# Set isSensor for b2Body dynamically

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, fixture

I just want to change isSensor for my b2Body in some workflow moment.
What i do:

```
b2Fixture *fixture = currentBody->GetFixtureList();
if (...)
{
   fixture->SetSensor(false);
}else
{
   fixture->SetSensor(true);
}
```

But I didn't find any way to Set this fixture to body back. Please advice way to do this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This will set all the fixtures on a body to be sensors. . Once you've done this, you done have to commit it back to the body, the body already has a reference to the fixtures.

```
-(void) setIsSensor:(bool)isSensor
{
    for (b2Fixture *fixture = body->GetFixtureList(); fixture; fixture = fixture->GetNext())
    {
        fixture->SetSensor(isSensor);
    }
}
```